# Convert a function with callback in a promise (Node.js) (OpenTok)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, opentok, tokbox

**MY ACTUAL CODE (THAT WORKS!)**

I've created a function with callback to create sessions and generate tokens for OpenTok, that exports itself to application.

*The function*

```js
//Dependencies
var opentok = require('./ot').opentok;
var apiKey = require('./ot').apiKey;
var apiSecret = require('./ot').apiSecret;

//Define variables
var sessionId;
var token;

//Define create newSession function
var newSession = function(callbackS){
  //Create Session (That allows to OpenTok)
  opentok.createSession({mediaMode:"relayed"}, function(err, session){
    if(err) throw err;
    else {
      //Define session object
      var objSession = {};
      //Obtain sessionId
      objSession.sessionId = session.sessionId;
      //Call generate token function
      newTok(objSession,callbackS);
    }
  });
}

//Define generate token function
var newTok = function(obj, fn){
    //Generate token (that allows to OpenTok)
    token = opentok.generateToken(obj.sessionId);
    //Store object (obj.tokenId) in token variable
    obj.tokenId = token;
    //Define "obj" in function context
    fn(obj);
}


//Export new Session with sessionId and token
module.exports.credentials = newSession;
```

*The APP*

```js
// Dependencies
var express = require('express');
var server_port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var apiKey = require('./ot').apiKey; //Obtain default apiKey
var credentials = require('./credentials').credentials(fun);


//function that was export from "credentials" (the function)
function fun(obj) {

//Define app
var app = express();

//Use "public" static folder
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

//Initialize the app
init();

//Routing
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  //Rendering variables in views
  res.render('index.ejs', {
    apiKey: apiKey,
    sessionId: obj.sessionId,
    token: obj.tokenId
  });
});

//Define Init
function init() {
  app.listen(server_port, function() {
    console.log('The app is running in localhost:' + server_port);
  });
}

}
```

**THAT I WANT:**

How I could convert my function that creates sessions and generates tokens in a promise that I can use into my app?

**UPDATE (08/01/2016) (14:53 VET)**

I've exported the function module in my app as follow:

```js
// Dependencies
var express = require('express');
var server_port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var apiKey = require('./ot').apiKey; //Obtain default apiKey

var credentialsPromise = require('./credentialsPromise').credentialsPromise(); //Obtain the promise

console.log(credentialsPromise);
```

And throw in console:

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

How I should use my promise in my app?

Comment: Why does `newTok` accept a callback when there's nothing async in it and it's a private function? Or is `opentok.generateToken` asynchronous and `newTok` just isn't calling it correctly?

Comment: newTok implicit function (generateToken) requires "sessionId" from createSession function, that is async.

Comment: If `opentok.generatetoken` is async, then `newTok` is not calling it properly (unless `token` is a promise? In which case `token`/`tokenId` is a slightly misleading name).

Comment: I've deleted the callback in newTok because isn't async (async is createSession) and works perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimal approach is as follows (see `***` comments):

```
var newSession = function(){
  // *** Return a promise
  return new Promsie(function(resolve, reject) {
    opentok.createSession({mediaMode:"relayed"}, function(err, session){
      // *** Reject on error
      if (err) {
          reject(err);
      } else {
        var objSession = {};
        objSession.sessionId = session.sessionId;
        // *** Have newTok call `resolve` with the object when done
        newTok(objSession, resolve);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Note that I didn't promise-ify `newTok`, though we could. It's not clear why `newTok` accepts a callback when nothing in it is asynchronous and it's a private function.

Using it looks like this:

```
newSession(/*...parameters...*/).then(
    function(result) {
        // All is good, use result
    },
    function(err) {
        // Error occurred, see `err`
    }
);
```

Comment: That's works! How I could use in the app?

Comment: I've delete the callback in newTok function and works.

Comment: @UlisesVargasDeSousa: Added usage example above

Comment: When I require the promise `var credentialsPromise = require('./credentialsPromise').credentialsPromise;` and print in console `console.log(credentialsPromise);` throws `[Function]`. But, where I should call the promise in the app?

Comment: @UlisesVargasDeSousa: Right at the top? I think it would be `credentialsPromise().then(fun);`.